# Xcode Error on Simulator but not on device when using persistentContainer

Tags: xcode, core-data, swiftui

When I simulate my app directly on my Iphone (iOS devices) I don't have any error.
But when I simulate my app in Xcode with virtual device (iOS simulators), app close due to an error.
Is it a bug of Xcode or should I change something ?

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class OriEPS {
    
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "OrientationEPS")
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                 fatalError("Unable to load persistent stores: \(error)") ///ERROR MESSAGE
            }
        }
        return container
    }()

var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
    return persistentContainer.viewContext
}
```

Error :
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unable to load persistent stores: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "(null)" UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/clementpignet/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B7D52736-52E5-496D-B477-707D31230BD4/data/Containers/Data/Application/8226C19D-7157-4BD5-9D29-E11D855706AD/Library/Application Support/OrientationEPS.sqlite, NSSQLiteErrorDomain=14}

Sometimes (if I navigate randomly in my app), console print me this error and app crash (but not at the same action in the app):
2020-11-05 12:46:11.937699+0100 OrientationEPS[10033:526048] [error] error:  Failed to load model named OrientationEPS
CoreData: error:  Failed to load model named OrientationEPS

Are these error linked together ?

Comment: Those errors say that the SQLite file could not be opened, but they don't give any information about why. Can you delete the app from the simulator and reinstall it? That might help.

Comment: Error still occurs after reinstalling